# opencv takedown video feed to frames

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to opencv and it's developing. I opened camera feed and i want to take the last frame after the 30s. and save the frame in Mat type object.
to ensure that i used imshow to display the used image. but i got errors please find below the code i used.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    VideoCapture cap(0);

    vector<Mat> frame;
    namedWindow("feed",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        frame.push_back(Mat()); // push back images of Mat type
        cap >> frame.back(); // take the last frame
        imshow("feed", frame);
        if (waitKey(30) >=0) { // wait 30s to take the last
            break;
        }
    }
return(0);
```

Error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= i && i < (int)v.size()) in getMat, file /Users/waruni/Documents/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 992
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/waruni/Documents/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:992: error: (-215) 0 <= i && i < (int)v.size() in function getMat
```

Comment: btw, waitKey() measures milliseconds, not seconds

Comment: i guess, you wanted: `imshow("feed", frame.back());`   (you can#t use imshow() with a whole vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As berak mentioned you cannot display a vector of matrices. So, `frame.back()` is probably what you want. I adapted your programme slightly.

```
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
  if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
      return -1;
  std::vector<cv::Mat> frame;
  cv::namedWindow("feed", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  for(;;)
    {
      cv::Mat temp;
      cap >> temp;
      frame.push_back(temp);
      cv::imshow("feed", frame.back());
      if (cv::waitKey(30*1000) >=0) { // wait 30s to take the last
          break;
        }
    }
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: it works but memory increases continuously. any idea. i want to to real time processing.

Comment: I think that's quite normal because you store continuously every image as a vector element. Do you need the "old" images? I didn't changed that because I didn't know your purpose.